# How to get the Weight of Evidence (WOE) and Information Value (IV) in Python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I was wondering how to calculate the WOE and IV in python.
Are there any dedication function in numpy/scipy/pandas/sklearn?

Here is my example dataframe:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(100)


df = pd.DataFrame({'grade': np.random.choice(list('ABCD'),size=(20)),
                   'pass': np.random.choice([0,1],size=(20))
})
df
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Formulas for woe and iv:

[image]

Code to achieve this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(100)


df = pd.DataFrame({'grade': np.random.choice(list('ABCD'),size=(20)),
                   'pass': np.random.choice([0,1],size=(20))
})

feature,target = 'grade','pass'
df_woe_iv = (pd.crosstab(df[feature],df[target],
                      normalize='columns')
             .assign(woe=lambda dfx: np.log(dfx[1] / dfx[0]))
             .assign(iv=lambda dfx: np.sum(dfx['woe']*
                                           (dfx[1]-dfx[0]))))

df_woe_iv
```

## output

```
pass     0    1       woe        iv
grade                              
A      0.3  0.3  0.000000  0.690776
B      0.1  0.1  0.000000  0.690776
C      0.2  0.5  0.916291  0.690776
D      0.4  0.1 -1.386294  0.690776
```

Comment: it seems `iv` value will be caculated after the second run in python3. i have to write assign(..) twice to comfront this problem:`df_woe_iv = (pd.crosstab(df[feature],df[target],
                      normalize='columns')
             .assign(woe=lambda dfx: np.log(dfx[1] / dfx[0]))
             df_woe_iv = df_woe_iv.assign(iv=lambda dfx: np.sum(dfx['woe']*
                                           (dfx[1]-dfx[0]))))`. anyway, that a  excellent solution

Comment: Hi @Bhishan - I get `infinity` for `woe` and `iv`. could it be because I don't have records under the negative class? Should instances be present in both classes for `woe` and `iv` to generate

Comment: When `woe value is negative`, I also get `inf`. Is there any criteria that I should be aware before using `woe` and `iv`

Comment: @TheGreat The concept of weight of evidence is based on goods and bads (look at the formula). If there are no any values for either of those, then the WOE is possible.

Comment: From the formula you can see that WOE become very large when the # of negative examples in a group decreases or is zero. It helps to think in terms of the limit of WOE when # of negative examples approach zero. The limit is inf. You could add a little correction to the formula to avoid the inf issue. You can used this: AdjustedWOE = ln (((Number of non-events in a group + 0.5) / Number of non-events)) / ((Number of events in a group + 0.5) / Number of events))

Answer (score 4):

#### [Weight of Evidence (WOE)](https://www.listendata.com/2015/03/weight-of-evidence-woe-and-information.html)

> The **weight of evidence** tells the predictive power of an independent variable in relation to the dependent variable. Since it evolved from the credit scoring world, it is generally described as a measure of the separation of good and bad customers. "Bad Customers" refers to the customers who defaulted on a loan. and "Good Customers" refers to the customers who paid back loans.

> Many people do not understand the terms goods/bads as they are from a different background than the credit risk. It's good to understand the concept of WOE in terms of events and non-events. It is calculated by taking the natural logarithm (log to base e) of the division of % of non-events and % of events.

[image]

#### [Information value](https://www.listendata.com/2015/03/weight-of-evidence-woe-and-information.html)

> **Information value** is one of the most useful techniques to select important variables in a predictive model. It helps to rank variables on the basis of their importance. The IV is calculated using the following formula :

[image]

Mode detailed explanation at [WEIGHT OF EVIDENCE (WOE) AND INFORMATION VALUE (IV) EXPLAINED](https://www.listendata.com/2015/03/weight-of-evidence-woe-and-information.html)

Python Implementation

```
def iv_woe(data, target, bins=10, show_woe=False):
    
    #Empty Dataframe
    newDF,woeDF = pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame()
    
    #Extract Column Names
    cols = data.columns
    
    #Run WOE and IV on all the independent variables
    for ivars in cols[~cols.isin([target])]:
        if (data[ivars].dtype.kind in 'bifc') and (len(np.unique(data[ivars]))>10):
            binned_x = pd.qcut(data[ivars], bins,  duplicates='drop')
            d0 = pd.DataFrame({'x': binned_x, 'y': data[target]})
        else:
            d0 = pd.DataFrame({'x': data[ivars], 'y': data[target]})

        
        # Calculate the number of events in each group (bin)
        d = d0.groupby("x", as_index=False).agg({"y": ["count", "sum"]})
        d.columns = ['Cutoff', 'N', 'Events']
        
        # Calculate % of events in each group.
        d['% of Events'] = np.maximum(d['Events'], 0.5) / d['Events'].sum()

        # Calculate the non events in each group.
        d['Non-Events'] = d['N'] - d['Events']
        # Calculate % of non events in each group.
        d['% of Non-Events'] = np.maximum(d['Non-Events'], 0.5) / d['Non-Events'].sum()

        # Calculate WOE by taking natural log of division of % of non-events and % of events
        d['WoE'] = np.log(d['% of Events']/d['% of Non-Events'])
        d['IV'] = d['WoE'] * (d['% of Events'] - d['% of Non-Events'])
        d.insert(loc=0, column='Variable', value=ivars)
        print("Information value of " + ivars + " is " + str(round(d['IV'].sum(),6)))
        temp =pd.DataFrame({"Variable" : [ivars], "IV" : [d['IV'].sum()]}, columns = ["Variable", "IV"])
        newDF=pd.concat([newDF,temp], axis=0)
        woeDF=pd.concat([woeDF,d], axis=0)

        #Show WOE Table
        if show_woe == True:
            print(d)
    return newDF, woeDF
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on a piece of pyspark code to Ailurophile's answer.
I initially tried to use pandas but my dataset is too big such that it is unable to take convert.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.ml.feature import QuantileDiscretizer

def iv_woe_spark(data, target, bins=10, show_woe=False):
    # Empty DataFrames
    newDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Variable", "IV"])
    woeDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Variable", "Cutoff", "N", "Events", "% of Events", "Non-Events", "% of Non-Events", "WoE", "IV"])
    
    # Extract Column Names
    cols = [col for col in data.columns if col != target]
    
    for ivars in cols:
        if data.schema[ivars].dataType in ['integer', 'double'] and data.select(ivars).distinct().count() > 10:
            # Bin the data for continuous variables using QuantileDiscretizer
            discretizer = QuantileDiscretizer(numBuckets=bins, inputCol=ivars, outputCol=ivars+"_bin")
            datatemp = data.select(ivars, target)
            datatemp2 = discretizer.fit(datatemp).transform(datatemp)
            d0 = datatemp2.select(ivars+"_bin", target)
        else:
            d0 = data.select(ivars, target)
            d0 = d0.withColumnRenamed(ivars, ivars+"_bin")

        # Calculate the number of events in each group (bin)
        d = d0.groupBy(ivars+"_bin").agg(
            F.sum(target).alias('Events'),
            F.count(target).alias('N')
        )
        
        # Events
        total_events = d.select(F.sum('Events')).collect()[0][0]
        d = d.withColumn('% of Events', F.greatest(F.col('Events'), F.lit(0.5)) / total_events)

        # Non-Events
        d = d.withColumn('Non-Events', F.col('N') - F.col('Events'))
        total_non_events = d.select(F.sum('Non-Events')).collect()[0][0]
        d = d.withColumn('% of Non-Events', F.greatest(F.col('Non-Events'), F.lit(0.5)) / total_non_events)

        # WOE / IV
        d = d.withColumn('WoE', F.log(F.col('% of Events') / F.col('% of Non-Events')))
        d = d.withColumn('IV', (F.col('% of Events') - F.col('% of Non-Events')) * F.col('WoE'))
        d = d.withColumn('Variable', F.lit(ivars))
        
        # Compute IV for this variable and print it
        iv_value = d.agg(F.sum('IV')).collect()[0][0]
        print("Information value of " + ivars + " is " + str(round(iv_value, 6)))
        
        # Append IV and WoE data to woeDF
        temp_woe = d.toPandas()
        woeDF = pd.concat([woeDF, temp_woe], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
        
        # Append IV to newDF
        temp_iv = pd.DataFrame([(ivars, iv_value)], columns=["Variable", "IV"])
        newDF = pd.concat([newDF, temp_iv], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
        
        # Show WoE Table
        if show_woe:
            print(temp_woe)

    return newDF, woeDF

# newDF, woeDF = iv_woe_spark(data, target, bins=10, show_woe=True)
```

It is also important to check on the data itself. WOE doesn't work well with imbalances in the data and there might be some works that need to be done during binning. So for instance if you had 4 million rows of data and it had >1000 distinct values, but there are 3.9 million rows of 0.1, then the binning won't work.